# UISlider track height

Tags: swift3, uislider

I have implemented UISlider and I need to adjust track height.
I found this but its not working.

```
self.slider.trackRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> found this but its not working

Because you're using it wrong. You don't *call* it. You subclass, and *override* it.

However, the right approach is to supply new images for the track, with `setMinimumTrackImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage`.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p585slider/ch25p860slider/MySlider.swift

Comment: Did you try your "solution" it causes a problem when thumb image doesn't overlap the min and max slider image

Comment: Well it tells us all what's wrong, but doesn't really help with getting things to work.

Answer (score 15):

Ok...I used matt's answer + provided example and I customized the code for my needs.

```
let coinEnd = UIImage(/*HERE_LEFT_BLANK_IMG*/).resizableImage(withCapInsets:
        UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,7,0,7), resizingMode: .stretch)
.
.
.
.

override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var result = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
    result.origin.x = 0
    result.size.width = bounds.size.width
    result.size.height = 10 //added height for desired effect
    return result
}

override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
    return super.thumbRect(forBounds:
        bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
        .offsetBy(dx: 0/*Set_0_value_to_center_thumb*/, dy: 0)
}
```

then inherid this to my Slider and woala.

[image]

This is my desired result.

[image]

All hail matt...thank you.