# Custom UISlider visualisation error (thumb position, track edge...)

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

this is my first time asking question here, if there is any part unclear in my question, please let me know, thank you.

So I am new to iOS, recently for a project I created a custom slider which looks like a iOS-style switch. Below is my code:

```
    @IBDesignable
    class CustomSlider: UISlider {

        @IBInspectable var trackWidth: CGFloat = 70
        @IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 30
        @IBInspectable var thumbHeight: CGFloat = 30
        private var thumbTouchSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 30)


        override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: trackHeight))
        }


        override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {

            var thumb = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)

            thumb.size.height = thumbHeight
            return thumb.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }


        override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
            let increasedBounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: -thumbTouchSize.width, dy: -thumbTouchSize.height)

            let containsPoint = increasedBounds.contains(point)
            return containsPoint
        }


        override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
            let percentage = CGFloat((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue))
            let thumbSizeHeight = thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect:trackRect(forBounds: bounds), value:0).size.height
            let thumbPosition = thumbSizeHeight + (percentage * (bounds.size.width - (2 * thumbSizeHeight)))
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            return touchLocation.x <= (thumbPosition + thumbTouchSize.width) && touchLocation.x >= (thumbPosition - thumbTouchSize.width)
            }
    }
```

This is how it looks :

custom UISlider initial state

[image]

when thumb moves towards right end

[image]

custom UISlider max. value

[image]

As you can see, 
(1) I set same height for the track and the thumb, however the thumb is not in the vertical center of the track, which does not look good. 
(2) when I pull the slider to the right end, the edge becomes flat which should not happen (edges should always remain round like the initial state).

I tried all the suggested solutions, none solved my problem. Please help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change your `trackHeight` from `30` to `31` you should see the Thumb properly centered vertically. I'm not sure what else you are trying to do?

Comment: @DonMag  Thank you very much for your edit and reply. However I tried your solution, it didn't work, my thumb is still not centered vertically :(

Comment: Dumb question maybe, but what if you changed the height by more than 31? Say 32, or 40?

Comment: @dfd  Hi I tried different values, no luck, the thumb either sticks to the top or to the bottom. Thanks anyway

Comment: does anyone knows the solution to the 2nd question (round edge becomes flat)? It's actually more important

Comment: @SoftwareProgrammierung - I've seen a lot of references to problems with modifying the `UISlider` - such as you are running into. You *might* want to go a different direction, and build your own slider. Here is one article that may help - while it is solving a different issue, it looks like a good example of a purely custom slider implementation., and it should be pretty easy to modify it for your needs: https://alexanderbatalov.com/journal/2015/2/23/how-to-implement-custom-uislider-with-swift-2

Comment: Regards to the first question: I tried playing with tracks and thumb images and remember having issues. Maybe you could change the height of the tracks? Even if you need to "remove" or make the bottom pixel clear. (Instead of trying to increase the thumb image size, decrease the track image/pattern.)

Comment: As for rounded tracks, I'm not seeing enough code to know what the issue is. I'll make a guess that your *minimum* track only has a rounded left side, and possibly your *maximum* track only has a rounded right side?

Comment: @DonMag I will check that out, thank you for the info.

Comment: @dfd  yes I tried that before and all the ways that I can think of, all of them don't look good. And my boss want the track and the thumb have same height, so....  Thanks though

Comment: @dfd  I didn't use images for the min and max track, I only set the height of the track,  I think the default UISlider has round corners on both sides.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Check out the answer from @matt here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959164/uislider-track-height#41959381 - also, look at the OP's answer. Maybe there's something in their code that makes a difference.