# Slider - incorrect color at the beginning and in the end

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a custom slider where i have to increase slider's height (thickness). The code looks like this:

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider
{   
    override open func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var defaultBounds = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        let newHeight: CGFloat = 20
        
        return CGRect(x: defaultBounds.origin.x,
                      y: defaultBounds.origin.y + defaultBounds.size.height/2 - newHeight/2,
                      width: defaultBounds.size.width,
                      height: newHeight)
    }
}
```

The height is increased, but the problem now is that slider is not colored properly at the beginning and in the end. For example, at the beginning it now looks like this:
[wrong color at the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj26f.png)

After some point the color becomes correct and fills blue: [correct color after some point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W94nJ.png)

In the end there is the same problem, at first everything works as expected: [normal behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z0eS.png)

But then after some point the color becomes updated to blue too soon: [wrong color in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C4Xd.png)

Has anyone experienced anything similar before? Is there any solution for this?

I have tried using `setMinimumTrackImage` and `setMaximumTrackImage` instead of `minimumTrackTintColor` and `maximumTrackTintColor`, it works, but i cannot use it because when i rotate screen - slider stretches and the image which i am using stretches as well, so slider's corner radius looks stretched and not the same as it has to be.

Also an interesting fact is that the more I increase slider height - the later the correct color appears at the beginning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959164/uislider-track-height might help

Comment: @CSmith thank you for the feedback, i tried but it didn't work unfortunately:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since setting track images is working and the only issue is stretched corners, the latter can be solved by using `resizableImage(withCapInsets:)` on your track images, so only the middle part of the image will be stretched and the rest will remain untouched.

These articles cover the topic in great details:

https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-stretchable-button-uiedgeinsetsmake/

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-make-resizable-images-using-resizableimagewithcapinsets